# Does this question require any calculus to solve?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, collision, textbook-erratum

So, I came across this question in a book,

> Two spherical bodies of mass $M$ and $5M$ and radii $R$ and $2R$, respectively are released in free space with initial separation between their centers equal to $12R$. If they attract each other due to gravitational force only, then the distance covered by the smaller body just before the collision is:
>
> (A)0.16J,
>
> (B)1.00J,
>
> (C)0.67J,
>
> (D)0.34J

Now we know by the universal law of gravitation, **F=GM1M2/(R^2)**. If we divide **F** by **M1** or **M2** then we get the acceleration of **M1** and **M2** respectively. But there is a problem. The values of acceleration that we get here are valid at distance **R** only. Since due to action of force on the bodies they get attracted, the separation between them decreases consequently and constantly, and thus the value of acceleration for each body changes too. So, equations of motions cannot be used due to changing acceleration. Now I don't know much, but probably either my method of approaching the question itself is wrong and this question can be solved with common mathematics only or this question does require calculus (which again I don't know either).

Comment: How is distance measured in Joules?

Comment: Joules of energy and the displacement can be related using the formula for work being, **W=F.S** where F is the force and S is the displacement. @JonCuster

Comment: Have you thought about conservation of momentum?  That method definitely does NOT require calculus.

Comment: Well, the multiple choice answers given obviously relate to another question. Yes, the question can be answered without calculus - see Rob's answer below.

Comment: W=F.S doesn’t apply because F isn’t constant.

Comment: Some users are doubting that the book actually says what you claim it says, because they don’t believe that a physics textbook could be that low-quality. You could settle the issue by posting a scan (although normally this is highly discouraged).

Comment: This problem only requires knowing that the center of mass doesn't move in the implied coordinate system. And (E) none off the above, since for $M>>m$ it moves $12R-2R-R=9R$ and $M=m$ is moves $9R/2\gt 1$...so no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The multiple-choice answers are an editing mistake. No one measures distances in joules.

You suggest in a comment that perhaps the intention is to integrate over the motion to find work done.  But you don't have enough information to find an absolute energy.  You could justify any of the "options" with a suitable choice of $M$ and $R$, but you would have to invent those values.

The intended problem seems to be to find the location of the "barycenter," which does not require calculus.

Consider naming and shaming this poorly-edited book, or perhaps tossing it in the garbage, depending on how many similar errors it contains.

Comment: If you want to name and shame someone then name and shame the guy who didn't read the question carefully, that's not the book's fault but the reader's.

Comment: @Yukterez I don’t understand. Are you saying that the question misstates what is in the book?

Comment: @Ghoster - of course, or who do *you* trust more: a book, or a low reputation user who's been here for 2 weeks? I've never seen a book like that in real life, but I've seen plenty of users like that on the internet. There's no way in hell a book confuses Joules with meters, especially if it gives only symbolic values like M and R. The smaller and heavier body travelled 1.5R and the lighter and larger body 7.5R (1.5+7.5+1+2=12 and 7.5/1.5=5) or if it were point masses 2R and 10R (that would be easy since the distances are proportional to the masses).

Comment: @Yukterez I assume the question was asked in good faith. The most likely explanation is that the multiple- choice answers belong to a nearby question, or a deleted question. I have seen such mistakes in textbooks, especially in first editions.